# C# generic constraints: Force two generic types to be different

Tags: c#, generics, generic-constraints

I've got a class with two generics and two indexers (such that t1->t2 and t2->t1.)

```cs
public class Mapper<T1,T2>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<T1,T2> _forward;
    private readonly Dictionary<T2,T1> _reverse;

    public T2 this[T1 val] 
    {
        get => _forward[val];
        set => _reverse[value] = val;
    }

    public T1 this[T2 val] 
    {
        get => _reverse[val];
        set => _forward[value] = val;
    }
}
```

Obviously if I tried to use a `Mapper<char,char>` the compiler would complain because it couldn't decide which indexer to use. How do I indicate to the compiler (and the reader) that `typeof(T1)!=typeof(T2)`?

Comment: The `return` should be removed from both properties.

Comment: Now I don't understand your problem anymore :-(

Comment: If you have a variable `Mapper<char,char> my_mapper`, then what happens when you call `my_mapper['5'] = '6';`

Comment: Your properties are overloads for as far as I can interpret. What is the goal of this class?

Comment: You won't be able to do this exactly. You will have to use creative naming in order to keep both sides from conflicting with each other, as well as use named methods instead of possibly duplicate indexers.

Comment: I guess one thing I could do is `throw` a type error if the types are the same, but I don't like doing runtime checks like that